# codeigniter join not working

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php 

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('venue');
$this->db->join('venue_type vt1', 'vt1.venue_type_id = venue.venue_type_id1');
$this->db->join('venue_subtype vst1', 'vst1.venue_subtype_id = venue.venue_subtype_id1');
$this->db->join('venue_type vt2', 'vt2.venue_type_id = venue.venue_type_id2');
$this->db->join('venue_subtype vst2', 'vst2.venue_subtype_id = venue.venue_subtype_id2');
$this->db->join('venue_type vt3', 'vt3.venue_type_id = venue.venue_type_id3');
$this->db->join('venue_subtype vst3', 'vst3.venue_subtype_id = venue.venue_subtype_id3');
$this->db->where('venue_id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

i have venue table it has more then 1 field relation b/w  venue_type. When i try to give first relation

```
 <?php
 $this->db->join('venue_type vt1', 'vt1.venue_type_id = venue.venue_type_id1');
 $this->db->join('venue_subtype vst1', 'vst1.venue_subtype_id = venue.venue_subtype_id1');
```

its working fine , but i try to access whole its not working.

Please Help me. (It may simple but i stuck)

By Saravanan.

Comment: Do you get errors? In PHP or CI? Turn error_reporting() ON and look at the log. Also try echo $this->db->last_query(); so see what query is being generated.

Comment: look at your where condition it has a fault it should be like this $this->db->where('venue.venue_id',$id);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use alias for multiple joins.

SELECT `st_id`, `table1`.`us_login`, `table2`.`us_login`
FROM (`stream`)
LEFT JOIN `users` AS table1 ON `table1`.`us_id` = `stream`.`st_id_user_from`
LEFT JOIN `users` AS table2 ON `table2`.`us_id` = `stream`.`st_id_user_to`

see the link: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/151176/

Answer (score 0):

There's no `$this->db->from` function in **Codeigniter**. Use instead `$this->db->select('venue.*')`